# How to continue after git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I face the following issue:
I made GIT rebase of the develop branch into my branch, I mean when I am in my branch, I did :

> git rebase develop

Then I fixed the merge conflicts, after that I called "GIT add ."
And finally the rebase was done, but then I say

> git status

I get:
On branch my_branch
Your branch and 'origin/my_branch' have diverged,
and have 50 and 39 different commits each, respectively.

And I do not know how to continue.
Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

When you rebase, you are creating a completely separate history from what the branch had before. If you had already pushed the branch before and you are tracking it, then after a rebase you will get a lot of revisions that are behind (the original revisions) and a lot of revisions forward (the new revisions of develop that were not present on the branch when you pushed it before plus the rebase revisoons). All in all: business as usual. If you are ok with the new history of the branch, `force pushing` it will solve the issue.